# Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and netcoreapp3.0 is not compatible?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard, I've always thought netcoreapps3.0 and even 2.0 could reference as low as netstandard 2.0.
But in this project for example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

But I get this weird error:

```
Error       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions doesn't support netcoreapp2.1. Consider updating your TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 or later.  ConsoleApp1 ...\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\6.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.targets
```

So I'm not sure anymore because [DependencyInjections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection)
is compatible netstandard 2.0 so any netcore app > 2.0 should be able to reference it right?
Thanks!!

Comment: Message says that you can't  use  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection  version 6.0 with   <.net core 3.1  and suggest you to update your  project to >=netcoreapp3.1.

Did you try to use lower versions of  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection  ,4-5?